# Connect android application to asp.net mvc back-end

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, service

I'm currently working on an mvc project meant to keep scores for students on certain sporting events, we are using a context class to create database tables code first into an existing database, the writing and reading in mvc works completely, we have a certain actionresult that returns a list of results that a student got, working with a studentId.

For this project we are also building an android app in which a student can logg on and view a list of his results (which the actionresult in mvc returns)

In our database we also have tables that work with mvc4's simple membership provider.

I was wondering what the best way was to connect our android application with our mvc project to acces the actionresult that returns the list.

I've been reading about an asp.net services project which could act as a link between our mc project and our android project, but I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this

also I was wondering if it was possible to log in using the credentials from mvc4's simple membership provider on our android app

Comment: I think if I can use the existing actionresults that are in our mvc project, I could use the login that we have already written for our website on our android app

Comment: I've been looking around for a solution ever since I posted this, I'm still finding a lot of sites and topics telling me to use REST to make the connection between the two.

I was wondering if someone could advise me as to how I should define my service and how to call it with my android application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way i can think of is ASP .NET Web API, as your front end application will have UI on android calling JSON result from an Web Api controller will help. you can also host this application separately and call from android, MVC or any other front end application reusing code